# WSGI(gevent) logging to stdout and stderr

Tags: python, logging, flask, wsgi, gevent

I'm trying to log my application and I want to use the `logging` module for it. The application is running in a docker-container, which made me to log to the stdout and stderr so I can see it in the docker logs. Unfortunately only my root logger is working who is writing to file. I already searched for this case, but I was unable to find a solution.

For better reference:

config.ini

```
[loggers]
keys=root, info

[handlers]
keys=debug, info

[formatters]
keys=debug, info, error

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=debug

[logger_info]
level=INFO
handlers=info
qualname=docker.info
propagate=0

[handler_debug]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=debug
args=('.logs', 'a+')

[handler_info]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=info
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_debug]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_info]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

main.py

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig(fname='logger.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()
from gevent import pywsgi

# some logging here

http_server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, log=logger)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: The name of the logger is related to `__name__`. `root` is a special case. `info` will apply for the package / module `info` only (everything starting with 'info' or 'info.')

Comment: So I would need to rename info to root if I want to log to stdout?

Comment: Got it, I removed every other logger and added all the handlers to the root logger. It's working now. If you wan't you can answer this question and I will mark it as solved.